# make prepare;make scripts

Tags: kernel, drivers

When installing some drivers ( ex: nvidia, mellanox )

I need to do the followings first for kernel:

```
make oldconfig
make prepare
make scripts
```

What are these steps do? what needs it?

Comment: [Partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178526/what-does-make-oldconfig-do-exactly-in-the-linux-kernel-makefile). I suggest Google or similar for the two other make targets.

Comment: Those are targets in the `Makefile`, that invoke recipes as part of the build process. Read `man make` and read the `Makefile`.